# What is the term for 2 persons having the same last name?

Tags: terminology

What is the term for 2 persons having the same last name?

and, please, add some examples of usages

Comment: *Namesake*, perhaps?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul it is correct way? I read that word had several meaning like same geographical or national names, not only last names

Comment: It's perfectly OK. Wait for other members to share their ideas. 

Comment: Your namesake is someone you share a name with. I don't know of a special word for sharing a surname.